# свойство transform:rotate

Tags: css, css3

как мне сделать так чтобы при активации картинка не просто поворачивалась и сразу возвращалась в предыдущие положение, а оставалась пока я на нее опять не нажму?

Comment: что тут имеется ввиду по _активацией_?

Comment: что такое активация? скорее всего написать на js.

Comment: "опять не нажму" судя по всему, активация это и есть нажатие

Comment: при активации - это при нажатии...то есть как со псевдоелементом :active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Вариант на Javascript

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var arrow = document.getElementById('arrow');
    arrow.onclick = function() {
      this.style.transform = (this.style.transform == "rotate(90deg)") ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(90deg)"
    }
}
```

```css
#arrow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/" alt="" />
</div>
```

### Вариант на CSS

```css
input {
  display: none
}
img {
  transition: all 1s
}
input:checked + img {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<label for="arrow">
  <input type="checkbox" id="arrow" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/" alt="" />
</label>
```